# Heat=Total KE+ Total PE so when a substance reaches it's melting point its KE remains constant but its PE increases so shouldn't temperature increase?

Tags: thermodynamics

I have a beaker full of a known volume of water and it's heated until it reaches its boiling point, temperature readings were taken by a temperature data logger for a known time period at known time intervals.

After reaching its boiling point the temperature seems to be constant at 373.15K, but its molecular potential energy is still increasing and according to the formula Heat=Total Internal Energy=Total KE + Total PE.

So if PE increases shouldn't the internal energy and as a result the temperature reading increase too?

Comment: See [Latent heat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_heat)

Comment: $Q = ∆K + ∆U + ∆E_{int}$ is the correct equation

Comment: Total energy should also include the energy of the steam that is produced.

Answer (score 1):

> Heat=Total KE+ Total PE s

No that is not true. The total microscopic KE + total microscopic PE is the total ***internal energy*** of the substance. Heat is *energy transfer* due solely to temperature difference. Heat is not the internal energy of the substance. Heat is not the temperature of the substance. You need to understand the difference  between heat, temperature, and internal energy.

> So if PE increases shouldn't the internal energy and as a result the
> temperature reading increase too?

How do you conclude the temperature increases too? Only the PE component of the internal energy increases.

The equation should be

Total internal energy = Total internal KE + Total internal PE

and then

Total change in internal energy = Total change in internal KE + Total change in internal PE.

Since temperature is a measure of average molecular KE and since temperature is constant in the boiling process, there is no change in internal KE during boiling. Therefore, for the boiling process

Total change in internal energy = total change in potential energy.

Regarding the role of heat:

Heat that causes a substance to change phase (melt/freeze or vaporize(boil)/condense) without causing a temperature change is referred to as  “latent heat”. It results in a change in internal potential energy.

Heat that causes a change in temperature of a substance without causing a phase change is referred to as “sensible heat”. It results in a change internal kinetic energy.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Better mention the specific latent heat of vaporization to answer why only the PE increases not KE during change of state

Answer (score 0):

The heat supplied to a solid substance at its melting point (called [latent heat of fusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_heat) ) is utilized in overcoming the intermolecular interactions in the solid as it is melting into a liquid -- a first-order transition. Consequently, the temperature remains constant until the melting is complete.

Answer (score 0):

> according to the formula Heat=Total Internal Energy=Total KE + Total PE

This isn't a valid formula. The correct formula is $\Delta U = Q - W$ where the internal energy $U=KE+PE$. You cannot ignore the $\Delta$ nor can you ignore the $W$. In your case the system is at constant (atmospheric) pressure, so the work can be written $W=p\Delta V$. During evaporation $\Delta V \ne 0$ so $W$ cannot be neglected.

> So if PE increases shouldn't the internal energy and as a result the temperature reading increase too?

Not necessarily. Inside the water are a large number of internal "degrees of freedom" where energy can be stored. They include all forms of internal energy, including KE and PE and degrees of freedom like vibrational modes that are mixtures of both KE and PE. The thermal energy per degree of freedom* is $E_T=k_B T$ where $k_B$ is the Boltzmann constant and $T$ is the temperature. The internal energy is $U=n E_T$ where $n$ is the number of internal degrees of freedom, each storing the thermal energy.

As $U$ increases, then by $U = n E_T=n k_B T$ it seems that so does $T$. So, at first glance it does seem like your concern is justified. However, what happens is that in $U=n E_T$ the $n$ is not constant. At phase changes like evaporation there is a sudden increase in $n$.

The issue is that molecules are quantum-mechanical. So some degrees of freedom require a certain minimum threshold of energy before they can be filled. If $E_T$ is less than this minimum threshold then no energy is stored in that degree of freedom. Then, when $E_T$ becomes large enough, some degrees of freedom that were previously "frozen out" begin to become filled. All of the added $Q$ goes into filling these newly-available degrees of freedom, and $E_T$ does not increase further until they are all filled.

Once the phase change is fully complete, then all of the new degrees of freedom are filled, $n$ becomes constant again, and further $Q$ increases $E_T$ and thus the temperature.

*These are statistical distributions and expectation values, but for clarity I am not worrying about that and just treating it all as one value

Answer (score 0):

Only the mean kinetic energy is related to temperature:
$$\langle K_E\rangle=\frac{3}{2}kT=\frac{1}{2}mv^2$$

Where k is the Boltzmann's constant and T is the temperature in kelvin.

You need to understand the *specific latent heat* of a material which is **the amount of energy required to change the state of 1 kg of the material without change of temperature**.

If it takes an amount of energy Q to change the state of a mass m of a substance, then the specific latent heat of that substance L is given by the equation:

$L$ = $\frac{Q}{m}$

Therefore, the change of state is always associated with the increase of decrease of PE not KE and so there is no temperature change.

NOTE:

The change from solid to liquid is called **specific latent heat of fusion**

The change from liquid to gas is called **specific latent heat of vaporization**